# BeautifulSoup4, how do I grab <td> and it's class within a <tr>?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build a webscraper, but I'm uncertain on where to progress with the syntax.

```
    content = soup.find_all('td', class_ ='serviceListing')
 


for property in content:
    name = property.find('a').text 
    details = property.find('span').text


    pageList = {
        'Name' : name,
        'Details' : details
    }

    serviceList.append(pageList)
    
print(serviceList)
```

---

```
Source Code:
    <tr>
       <td id = 'xx' class='serviceListing' style='yy: zz;' bgcolor="FFFFFF")
             <a id = "content" href="displayService,aspx?id=147674">Location Name</a>
               &nbsp;
             <a href="servicesprovidedinFrench.aspx" class... </a>
             <br>
             <span id = "content" class='regtext">801 location</span>
       </td>
       <td valign="top" class='serviceListingCity" ... </td>
            <span id="contentplaceholderPhone" class"regtext">905 905 9055 </span>
       </td>
       <td> ... </td>
```

I understand my code is only grabbing the first iteration of the  code. What would be the correct syntax to return every iteration of  within ?

Currently, I'm only able to grab "a location name /a" and 'span id 801 location /span'?

How would I go about grabbing the second iteration of td and 'span 905 905 9055 /span' within the serviceListingCity class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question right: do you want to find information next to `<td class="serviceListing">`? If yes, you can do `.find_next()` method:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
    <tr>
       <td id="xx" class="serviceListing">
             <a id="content" href="displayService,aspx?id=147674">Location Name</a>
               &nbsp;
             <a href="servicesprovidedinFrench.aspx">...</a>
             <br>
             <span id="content" class="regtext">801 location</span>
       </td>
       <td valign="top" class="serviceListingCity">
            <span id="contentplaceholderPhone" class"regtext">905 905 9055</span>
       </td>
       <td> ... </td>
    </tr>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for prop in soup.select('td.serviceListing'):
    name = prop.find('a').text
    details = prop.find('span').text
    phone = prop.find_next('span', id='contentplaceholderPhone').text

    print(name)
    print(details)
    print(phone)
```

Prints:

```
Location Name
801 location
905 905 9055
```